# list item with asterix

Tags: css

is it possible to increment asterixes in a ordered list ? So if I have something like

```
<ol class="ast">
<li>item 1</li> 
<li>item 2</li> 
<li>item 3</li> 
</ol>
```

that would show up on my page as follows

*   item 1
**  item 2
*** item 3

using css ?

Comment: What's an asterix? Do you mean asterisk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but you'd have to un-style the list (`list-style:none`) and use the "before:" pseudo class to absolutely-position your asterisk, combined with `n-th` child to set the number of asterisks.

Something like this, but you'll have to tweak it a bit.

```
ul, li {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
  list-style:none      
}

li {
   padding-left:20px; 
}

li:nth-child(1):before {
   content: "*" 
}

li:nth-child(2):before {
   content: "**" 
}
```

Comment: So if there are 100 items you'd need 100 `content: "*"` rules? Might as well just skip the CSS and hard code it in the HTML.

Comment: You can always do it using JavaScript.

Comment: Fair enough, but I have a maximum of 5 so it's feasible to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS `symbols()` function allows you to create something similar to what you're looking for.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/symbols.

An example is to style a list like:

```
ol {
  list-style: symbols(symbolic "*");
}
```

While the above code auto-increments the number of asterisks per each `<li>` like what you want, the amount of asterisks grows to the left instead of to the right like what you're after.

Also, once you get past a certain number of list items, the number of asterisks will grow beyond your available white space. [See this demo for an example of this problem](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYdoYz).

Also, `symbols()` is currently only supported in FireFox version 35 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

There is always a way:

```css
ul {
     list-style: "*";
}

li {
     padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I don't beleive there is a way to handle it for arbitrary depth. Diodeus's solution would handle a known maximum depth at the expense of a lot of CSS code.

Comment: @downvoter - why? (pls note the date of my comment, things likely change in 6.5 years)

Answer (score 0):

In case your target is only Safari or iOS, you might use a `list-style-type` of `asterisks`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type